# I have Enabled the sharing setting "Secure guest user record access" that's why i am not able to access child object of Master object in SF

Tags: apex

I Have 3 Object suppose A, B, And C. A is a master of B and B is Master of C that 3 object are used in site's VF page. So issue is in  these sharing setting "Secure guest user record access" is enabled so not able to do DML operation on Child record of A. Means That B and C is not accessible to Gust User. so need access of that child record of A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and was able to resolve this by using "[without sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm)`" in apex during the query.

Also, note that there must be [extreme caution](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_guest_record_default_owner_best_practices.htm&type=5) using this.

The recommendation would be to run all quries in a diffrent class which used the keyword "without sharing" (just for access)

Comment: Thank you Abhijith it is working, But that class is used for payment transaction so we can't remove the class level sharing.

Comment: yeah so the recommendation would be to move the query to another class (like a model class) which is labelled "without sharing" and get data from this model class...